# Open .z file in python and decompress it

Tags: python

I stumbled upon a quite interesting exercise. I have some files compressed using the lzw algorithm and I'm trying to open and decompress them in python. How do I read in the file to go through the characters? I think I can figure out how to decompress it once I get how I should read it properly.

If I only do:

```
output = open("compr1.z")
text = output.read()
```

I get this output

```
€eÀlð, wðrÀd
```

What's the right way of reading in the file?

Comment: https://pythonhosted.org/lzw/lzw-module.html

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a read through that and see if I can create my own.